# Looker: Run queries only when the dashboard window in visible

Tags: looker

We have a looker dashboard that reloads all of the tiles automatically every 5 mins. But this tends to be left open in the background and triggers a lot of queries which runs without purpose, is there a way to run the queries only when the tab or window with the dashboard is on the foreground?